# Implement multiple timers in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, backgroundworker

I'm working on a windows forms app where I have several so called "services" that poll data from various services like Twitter, Facebook, Weather, Finance. Now each of my services has its individual polling interval setting so I was thinking I could implement a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` for each of my services and set its `Interval` property accordingly so that each timer would fire an event at the preset interval that will cause the service to pull new data preferably async through a `BackgroundWorker`.

Is this the best way to do it? or will it slow down my app causing performance issues. Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good way to do it but, if the number of sources is pretty high, you may consider to use a scheduler instead of multiple timers (because timers are a - not so light - finite resource).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with one `Timer`, just needs smarter approach to interval:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int facebookInterval = 5; //5 sec
    int twitterInterval = 7; //7 sec

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000; //1 sec
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        facebookInterval--;
        twitterInterval--;

        if (facebookInterval == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Getting FB data");
            facebookInterval = 5; //reset to base value
        }

        if (twitterInterval == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Getting Twitter data");
            twitterInterval = 7; //reset to base value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought about that, it's the standard approach when working with timers on microcontrolers where resources are limited. However the questions is which way is more efficient: multiple timers or single timer with internal counters? It seems to me that the second way would be more efficient, resources wise. Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine that complex structure like `Timer` is much bigger than simple integer ;) Smaller = faster to access and process.

Answer (score 1):

you do not really need BackgroundWorker, as WebClient class has Async methods.

so you may simply have one WebClient object for each of your "service" and use code like this:

```
facebookClient = new WebClient();
facebookClient.DownloadStringCompleted += FacebookDownloadComplete;
twitterClient = new WebClient();
twitterClient.DownloadStringCompleted += TwitterDownloadComplete;

private void FacebookDownloadComplete(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        string str = (string)e.Result;
        DisplayFacebookContent(str);
    }
}
private void OnFacebookTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     if( facebookClient.IsBusy) 
         facebookClient.CancelAsync(); // long time should have passed, better cancel
     facebookClient.DownloadStringAsync(facebookUri);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I didn't mention I'm using API's where available, some have async methods some don't so I'll just have to adjust individually.