# Multiple Windows.Forms.Timer, slow application

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, timer

My problem is about performance having multiple Windows.Forms.Timer in a c# Forms app.

[image: Timers]

timerHora, for example, has a 1 sec interval, showing the current hour in a label.

I dont have any async method, so, when i run the app my GUI is not refreshing the hour label each second, i guess it is running in same thread as the rest of timers and it waits other functions to finish, so it sometimes refresh each second, and other times 2,3 or 4 seconds.

So... Can you recommend me best practices for handling this problem?

Comment: You can try reducing the number of timers, as presented in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314673/implement-multiple-timers-in-c-sharp). Also I recommend to check out `System.Timers.Timer`instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` Might provide some performance advantages.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it, if this Timer doesn´t work I think i'll try with threads

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` *does* use a separate thread for the callback. But you still need to synchronize with the UI to change the UI. It rather sounds like you're doing a lot more work on the UI thread than you should be doing. Separate the UI things from the blocking and computation and the UI will stay responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Task _task;
    CancellationTokenSource _token;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        _token = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(), _token.Token);            
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _token.Cancel();
        Application.DoEvents();
        _task.Wait();
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            _task.Dispose();
            _token.Dispose();
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void SetTime()
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        label1.Text = $"{dt.Hour}:{dt.Minute}:{dt.Second}";
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(SetTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this helped much, i have a question, if i want to run multiple methods, not only SetTime, need i to create multiple task? at onload method too?

Comment: Well, you may add multiple tasks, of course, and invoke specific methods inside each of them. But since they all will use same shared resource(UI), the invoke requests will be queued, not executed right away
So i would stick to the one task and may be several method invokes inside. With may be some logic to decide which one has to be called

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that the timmers event are to slow.
The timmers are executed in the main thread, so if your code is slow, you will slow all the form.

Try to do threads instead timmers

Comment: I need to apply intervals for that events, so i guess that i need Timers anyway? or am I wrong? Thanks ^^

Comment: @Ferus7 Usually, you'd use a timer to *start* the processing in background. Different requirements warrant different approaches - if you're just updating the UI, there's no point in using anything else than a winforms timer. If you need to update the UI from the database once in a while, you'd usually run the database update as a background task started on the timer event, and marshall the results back to the UI thread when they're ready (`await` makes this very easy most of the time).

Comment: Tried this @Luaan, thx, but i'm not able to refresh the ui every second where there are a bit heavy methods :S

Comment: @Ferus7 Again, don't do heavy methods on the UI thread. That's your real problem - the fact that timer events execute "later" is just one symptom of this problem. Regardless of the timers, the UI of your application is still unresponsive when the heavy methods execute, which is poor UX anyway. If a method takes long enough to be noticeable (20-200ms is a rough threshold, depending on exact circumstances), it shouldn't be on the UI thread.

Comment: Okay @Luann, really thank you, I´ll try to optimize it ^^